# Как установить правила для всех папок и подпапок в них?

Tags: apache, mod-autoindex

- Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно изменить правила для всех папок и подпапок?
- Искал в интернете, но не удалось найти то, что хотел получить.

Хочу настроить сервер так, чтобы `ReadmeName` работал для любых путей:

- `/`
- `/folder/`
- `/**/**/`

```xml
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
        ReadmeName \Apache\Explorer\footer.html
</IfModule>
```

Примечание: у меня есть полный доступ к серверу (включая `Apatch`, `Nginx`, `PHP`, и так далее), но менять глобальные настройки сервера - не сильно хочу.